# node_modules missing even after npm install in docker container

Tags: docker, npm-install

The Dockerfile being used:

```
FROM node:8-alpine

WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY . .
RUN npm install

CMD ["npm", "run", "serve"]

EXPOSE 8080
```

And the docker-compose.yml file:

```
version: '3'

services:
    app:
        container_name: app
        restart: always
        build:
            context: ./app
            dockerfile: Dockerfile
        ports:
            - "8080:8080"
        volumes:
            - ./app:/usr/src/app
            - ./logs:/logs
```

The folder structure is the following:

```
project/
|-- docker-compose.yml
|-- logs/
|-- app/
    |-- Dockerfile
    |-- package.json
```

When running `docker-compose up --build` from project/, the `npm install` step outputs the following after about one minute:

```
added 1684 packages from 1297 contributors and audited 36429 packages in 56.23s
found 0 vulnerabilities
```

However, at the `npm run serve` step, the output basically consists in saying that no npm module can be found, and among other things, this line:

> npm WARN Local package.json exists, but node_modules missing, did you mean to install?

How comes `npm install` is actually and definitely executed, but npm complains that `node_modules` cannot be found?

Answer (score 9):

I had the same problem and I solved it just following [this instruction](https://jdlm.info/articles/2016/03/06/lessons-building-node-app-docker.html). Add one line of code `- /usr/src/app/node_modules` to the docker-compose.yml file in the volumes:

```
volumes:
  - ${PWD-.}/name_of_your_app:/usr/src/app
  - /usr/src/app/node_modules
```

Comment: thanks, it's working fine, it installs node_modules in both container and locally

Answer (score 5):

Update: I just ended up using only `./app/src` folder as a volume, instead of `./app`.

This way, `/app/node_modules` is not overridden by the host's volume.

```
version: '3'

services:
    app:
        container_name: app
        restart: always
        build:
            context: ./app
            dockerfile: Dockerfile-dev
        ports:
            - "8080:8080"
        volumes:
            - ./app/src:/usr/src/app/src # <---- this
            - ./logs:/logs
```